How to set new ticks for axes in heatmap?
I have the following code where parameter1, 2, and alpha_values take decimal values. These are stored as numpy array.
I wanna use heatmap but for axes, I am going to use integer values. However, when I add values for ticks in x-axis, I face the following figure. I am wondering how I should set customized ticks and also reverse the order of values in y-axis such that the maximum value is on top and the smallest value is on the bottom.

import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

# Create a DataFrame to store the data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    r'$a$': np.round(parameter1,2),
    r'$\mathbb{E}(S)$': np.round(parameter2,2),
    'alpha_values': alpha_values
})
# Pivot the DataFrame to create a matrix suitable for a heatmap
heatmap_data = data.pivot(index=r'$a$', columns=r'$\mathbb{E}(S)$', values='alpha_values')
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("gray_scale", ["white", "blue"])


x_axis_labels = np.arange(-4, 13, 2)
xticklabels = [str(c) for c in x_axis_labels]
y_axis_labels = np.arange(0, 13, 2)

ax = sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap=cmap, annot=False, fmt=".2f",  vmin=0, vmax=1, xticklabels=xticklabels)


#ax.set_yticklabels(yticks[::-1])  # Reverse the y-axis labels

# Add a frame around the figure
for _, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
    spine.set_linewidth(1)



first add missing elements in code - so we could simply copy and run it.

if you want to reverse ytics then first you have to use functions with ax. like ax.get_yticks() and ax.set_yticklabels()

for reversing works for me ax.set_yticklabels( ax.get_yticklabels()[::-1] ) and as for putting ax.set_xticks([50, 75, 100], labels=['A', 'B', 'C']) where 50,75,100 are indexes of values/columns (not percents nor values in data) and it can be 4.5 to put in the middle of column 4
